# How do i make it so that when the user enters a number to check if it's odd or even and then the code asks the user to input 1 or 2 again

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print ("[1] Identify, [2] quit")
user = int(input())
while (user) == 1:
    num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    if (num % 2) == 0:
        print("{0} is Even".format(num))
    else:
         print("{0} is Odd".format(num))    
if (user) == 2:
    quit()
```

The code is firstly asking the user to input 1 or 2, the code will then ask the user to input a number and then the code will say if the number is odd or even but I'm trying to make it so that after the user has input the number to check if it's odd or even, it then asks to enter 1 or 2 again.

Comment: Hint: if you want `"[1] Identify, [2] quit"` to be printed more than once, it should probably be inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your first two lines inside the loop. Here's one way to do it:

```
while True:
    print("[1] Identify, [2] Quit")
    user = int(input())
    if user == 1:
        num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
        if (num % 2) == 0:
            print("{0} is even".format(num))
        else:
            print("{0} is odd".format(num))
    elif user == 2:
        break
quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it would be to put it all inside a while loop and exit if 2 is entered:

```
while True:
    user = int(input("[1] Identify, [2] quit "))
    if user==1:
        num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
        if not num%2:
            print("{0} is Even".format(num))
        else:
             print("{0} is Odd".format(num)) 
    else:quit()
```